# Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial (3.2) - Chapter 5 Rspec issue

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spork, railstutorial.org

I've completed Chapter 5 and all the exercises. As part of the final exercise, MH has you write tests for the ApplicationHelper method.

Once that is done, *individual* tests pass with:

- `shift-command-T` in ST2 (using the sublime-text-2-ruby-tests package)
- `rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` in the terminal
- `rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` in the terminal

However, if I run *all* tests with `rspec spec/` in the terminal I get this error:

```
/Users/anonymouscoward/rails/railstut/sample_app/spec/helpers/
application_helper_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized
constant ApplicationHelper (NameError)
```

If I run spork and try `rspec spec/` again, all tests pass.

I'm not sure I understand why this works the way it does, or whether I'll always need to have spork running in the future when I want to run all my tests. Thanks.

Comment: Which code is on line 1 in application_helper_spec.rb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe you forgot to require spec_helper.
If so, just insert this in the first line of application_helper_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. If I understand correctly, the Spork.prefork block in `spec_helper.rb` loads the Rails environment and makes ApplicationHelper available.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Thanks for the fix!

I found this response on another forum, which seems helpful in thinking about how Spork relates to Rspec.

> RSpec does not "run" spec_helper. By default, rspec loads files that
>   end with "_spec.rb" and it is up to those files to require
>   spec_helper.rb.
>   http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167768

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "ApplicationHelper" do
```

ApplicationHelper should be a string, not constant

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be. rspec allows class types in the describe clause. It will extrapolate the name when it prints it in the rspec output. It is actually preferable to do it this way to take advantage of rspec's implicit subject feature.